# Can't access to properties of superclass in C#

Tags: c#, subclass, perspectivecamera

I'm new in C#, actually I'm creating a subclass of a PerspectiveCamera

```
class VCamera : PerspectiveCamera
{

    private double m_AngleRadianX;
    private double m_AngleRadianZ;

    public VCamera()
    {
        m_AngleRadianX = 0.0;
        m_AngleRadianZ = 0.0;
        LookDirection = new Vector3D();          
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't access to LookDirection, which is a public property of PerspectiveCamera.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.media.media3d.perspectivecamera.aspx

Is it because LookDirection is inherited from ProjectionCamera!? I don't get it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your class isnt Public. Public Class VCamera : PerspectiveCamera

Comment: @derek that doesn't matter if it's the line in the constructor that fails

Comment: try PerspectiveCamera.LookDirection or the complete class path to it like: System.Windows.Media.Media3D.PerspectiveCamera.LookDirection

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: the error I get is : "The name LookDirection doesn't exit in the actual context". Setting the class public or using PerspectiveCamera.lookDirection doesn't work.

Comment: ...whereas if you create a new `PerspectiveCamera` you can set it just fine :-/

Comment: Yes if I create a new PerspectiveCamera, I can access the properties, but that is not the way I want to do it. (In fact I firstly done it this way, but it reveals to be inconvenient due to my implementation). My VCamera deals somes operations in order to move the camera, camera which is a property of a Viewport3D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `PerspectiveCamera` is `sealed` - you can't derive from it. VS doesn't give a very helpful error until you compile.